# Why do modern keyboards have Scroll Lock?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

The <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key is useless in the modern day, and some higher-end keyboards don't even have it:

[image: Logitech Wave Keyboard]

Same can be said for the <kbd>Pause</kbd> and <kbd>Break</kbd> keys, but however it pauses the BIOS POST output on many computers, so it's a useful key (some older games also use it to pause the game).

The <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key doesn't do anything: it doesn't even lock scrolling as its name suggests. I can understand that some older keyboards have this key, but not the newer ones such as the keyboards bundled with many OEM computers these days; it's not like any newer computer is likely to run an older operating system such as Windows 9x.
Games that use the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key may not even be compatible with newer operating systems.

Is there a historical reason for this or are keyboard designers just plain lazy to get rid of this useless key?

Comment: Actually, Microsoft Excel at least still uses the scroll lock key. I don't know of any other software that does off the top of my head, but as long as one popular program uses it, it probably won't go away.

Comment: Rolled back and edited so that `pause` and `break` are separate keys; on some keyboards such as my own they are separate keys.

Comment: The ```scroll lock``` key exists so that I can remap it to another keyboard macro :-)

Comment: Manufacturing processes are very expensive to setup and change. It is cheaper to leave the `scroll lock` key in place for the few people still using it.

Comment: Don't see it on my mac keyboard, but I guess I can conjure scroll lock with
SHIFT+FN+F12.

Comment: That toy in the photograph, despite being expensive, is certainly not a high-end keyboard! You might want [this](http://www.daskeyboard.com/daskeyboard-4-professional/), and yes it has a Scroll Lock.

Comment: The fact that manufacturing processes are expensive to set up does not explain why these keys are on keyboards that were designed in the last few years.

Comment: Great question.  Maybe of interest to you - my laptop (a 2015 dell xps) doesn't have a scroll lock key.  I suspect there is a strange combination of keys I could use if I really needed it, but there is nothing visual on the keyboard anymore to indicate it.  Or pause or break as it happens.  The thing I most miss is the turbo button on desktops :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are a zillion bits of legacy code out there many of which have appropriated the "junk" keys for application purposes.

You've not seen many of them because they are internal, mission-critical programs for which the cost of re-writing and re-training are huge.

To the best of my knowledge you can still put a floppy into a modern windows machine, run the 1985 version of Lotus 1-2-3 and it will work. Microsoft's most valuable feature is backward compatibility.

Comment: True, however most modern machines don't include floppy drives anymore.

Comment: I don't recall the last time I saw a floppy drive on a machine.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises you can however still get external ones. Serial to USB converter and you're good to go...

Comment: @DA01 I have, a few years ago. Bank was still using them to distribute security keys between offices. High encryption, specially modified drives, disks were unreadable on any other hardware but their own (hardware+software encryption, and formated to an custom format). They may have switched to some encrypted USB stick for that purpose by now, but that was still in use until recently.

Comment: @jwenting one of the security features of a such custom floppy-disks is that they are far more difficult to reverse-engineer than a custom USB drive.  That's just as much of a counter-usability UX pattern for the use-cases involved

Comment: Actually, you can't run old DOS programs in Windows. You can't even run 16-bit Windows apps (Windows 3.11) anymore. (You can run DOS Box, though, which will let you run the very old stuff, but DOS Box is not a Microsoft product.)

Comment: @JohnDeters thanks for the info, but color me dejected for now I must come up with a better example.

Comment: @JohnDeters Yes, but you can boot in DOS. I played Duke Nukem 3d on a laptop, without sound of course, but it runs no prob. But even for DOS I don't remember usage of scroll lock key.

Comment: There's nothing more sensical than putting a physical key that is useless in 99.999% of modern computing on _every computer keyboard in existence_. While Microsoft's most valuable feature is back-compat, it's the less-than-forward thinking that makes them lag behind the market in usability in, well, pretty much 100% of cases. It's not a good tradeoff. As an engineer myself, I can say that 40 year old features are costlier to maintain than update, and this is a _baaaad_ excuse.

Comment: @jwenting your concept of "high encryption" is exceptionally flawed if you think that _any_ floppy drive encryption is hard to break by modern standards. It is absolutely terrifying that a bank is distributing security keys via floppy disks "recently" (IE within the last 10 years).

Comment: Part of the reason that hardware can phase out is if it's unreliable/wears out: ZIP drives (click...click...click...) as well as 3.5" disks, so you'd have to replace it anyways, and at some point the cost to replace gets so high, it's smaller than the cost of switching.

Comment: @dudewad: IE is an old, awful browser. Whereas i.e. is the abbreviated form of the Latin phrase "id est", roughly meaning "that is". :-) You're welcome!

Comment: @LawrenceDol You are a gentleman and a scholar, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 70):

One major commonly used application that still supports <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> is **Microsoft Excel**. This makes sense if you work in spreadsheets all day and are used to navigating with the keyboard arrow keys more efficiently than the mouse. They still use it. In fact, when you google [excel scroll lock](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+scroll+lock&oq=excel+scroll+lock), the first thing on the list is *[Turn off Scroll Lock - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-off-Scroll-Lock-a8a5b32e-702e-428a-9466-4eb3529acba8)* wherein it explains why and how it is still used:

> ## **Turn off Scroll Lock**
>
> Usually, when a cell is selected in Microsoft Excel and you press the arrow keys, the selection moves between individual cells. However, if you press the arrow keys when Scroll Lock is on, you scroll one row or column at a time. Scroll Lock is a toggling lock key on the keyboard, just like the Caps Lock key. Once pressed, Scroll Lock is enabled. To use the arrow keys to move between cells, you must turn Scroll Lock off.

[Wikipedia says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_lock)

> **Window scrolling**
>
> ...
>
> Today, this particular use of <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> is rare. Modern programs honoring this behavior include IBM Lotus Notes, Forté Agent, Image-Line FL Studio, Renoise, Microsoft Excel, and on occasions Microsoft Word.
>
> Some text editors (such as Notepad++, Microsoft Visual Studio) exhibit similar behavior when the arrow keys are used with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> depressed.
>
> ...

My own Google searches are fruitless trying to find an explanation of what "on occasions" means.

The Wikipedia article also shows this question is not new. It quotes from the [*1983 January edition* of *PC Magazine*](http://books.google.ca/books?id=vy3cBZkjbZgC&lpg=PP1&pg=RA2-PA347&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true).

The article began with ...

> **PRODUCT REPORT / COREY SANDLER**
>
> ---
>
> ***An in depth look at a new PC-compatible keyboard
>
>   that for some users provides an appealing alternative
>
>   to the IBM original***.
>
> ## **Key Tronic's Soft Touch**

... and ended with:

> Oh, yes. About the "Scroll Lock" key on the IBM PC keyboard: Used with the Ctrl key, it is modified to server as a break when using a BASIC program. But by itself, IBM's "Guide to Operations" will only say it is an "inactive key."
>
> "What is it for?" Key Tronic's expert was asked. "I don't know," Tidden answered. "But we put it on ours, too." **/PC**

Comment: "I don't know," Tidden answered. "But we put it on ours, too." – awesome 

Answer (score 16):

To add a bit of history on the reason behind the scroll lock, quoting this [article](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eachaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Scroll_lock.html)

> The Scroll Lock key was meant to lock all scrolling techniques, and is
> a remnant from the original IBM PC keyboard, though it is not used by
> most modern-day software. In the original design, Scroll Lock was
> intended to modify the behavior of the arrow keys. When the Scroll
> Lock mode was on, the arrow keys would scroll the contents of a text
> window instead of moving the cursor. In this usage, Scroll Lock is a
> toggling lock key like Num Lock or Caps Lock, which have a state that
> persists after the key is released.

That said, as msw replied there are still reasons why the scroll lock is there as there are still softwares which use the scroll lock [namely](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eachaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Scroll_lock.html)

> Only a few modern programs still honor this behavior, such as Lotus
> Notes, Forté Agent, FL Studio, and Microsoft Excel.

That said, even though the need for the scroll lock has been deprecated, most keyboard manufacturers still install the scroll lock as it was part of the older system and they are not aware of what it does and install it to be on the safer side. To quote this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_lock#cite_note-sandler198301-3).

> IBM PC documentation called Scroll Lock an "inactive key". When PC
> Magazine asked an executive of keyboard manufacturer Key Tronic about
> the key's purpose, he replied "I don't know, but we put it on ours,
> too".

Comment: Congrats, your post now forms the Google definition of the scroll lock key. [See here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=what+is+the+scroll+lock+key+for&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=g0pEVu3GMKG3mwWZzaCQCQ)!

Comment: Deprecated, not depreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The fact that you have a key that is unused in any modern application (Excel excluded) and has a dedicated hardware indicator light, it is perfect for use with something like [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

For example, you can remap it so that the Scroll Lock key acts as a modifier to set your keyboard to use a different set of characters.  This thread has a script that gives you entire Greek alphabet, all with one simple toggle of the Scroll Lock key:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/113278-send-unicode-letters/

Personally, I have extended the Greek alphabet option further so that I can use Scroll Lock to give me a series of mathematical and engineering symbols as well, using the number and symbol keys.  And, because it all relies on the state of the Scroll Lock key, I can make use of every other modifier key too - with combinations of Shift (already used), Ctrl, Alt, the Windows key, that gives me maybe 16 layers?  (Maybe more with AltGr).  Something on the order of a thousand possible characters,* all without worry of conflicting with another app's shortcut keys?  That's any and every symbol you want, and/or a bunch of other languages, all easily switchable (and with a convenient light to tell you if you're in "special characters" or "normal characters" mode).

*Letter, number, symbol, and function keys are available, and in theory you could even re-map the navigation keys too (arrow, pgup/dn, home, end, delete, backspace, etc), or get really exotic and start using mouse keys/wheel...

Comment: While basically off-topic, this suggested method for leveraging the ScrollLock key is very insightful and great a UX concept.

Comment: I recommend you to use [this script](https://gist.github.com/kbauer/e8fee6514d124d5961f51fd7ba571bfd) instead for Unicode characters.

Answer (score 4):

Computer companies (Microsoft in particular) strive to be backward compatible. In addition to there being some software that still uses scroll lock (Excel has been mentioned in other responses), there is *hardware* that depends on scroll lock too.  For example, many KVM switches use it as a hot key to switch to another machine.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should instead be a comment.

Comment: "Backward compatibility" seems a perfectly sensible - and obvious - answer to me.  In point of fact, the Scroll_Lock is perfectly accessible in Linux/X (keycode 78 keysym 0xff14), and like any other key can be mapped to whatever the user chooses.  It's rather like the later "Windows" keys that have no standard use outside that OS, but can be redefined by each user.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ I was originally going to post it as a comment, but then I thought that someone would complain about using comments for answers.  But how is the keys utility for KVM switches any less of answer than the answer talking about how it's still used in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to legacy applications, some more recent applications use this key as a key that is unlikely to conflict with other applications.

For instance, the [XFire](http://www.xfire.com/) social gaming program has a chat overlay that be shown during full screen games. Games tend to have a lot of special key bindings, so XFire chose to use <kbd>Scroll Lock + X</kbd> as the hotkey to load the chat overlay because it was unlikely to conflict with other key bindings.

While this is not a reason for keyboard manufacturers to continue including a <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key, it shows that some developers still find use for it.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't used XFire in years, they may well have changed their default hotkey for this.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the Scroll Lock key in the Linux console while text is scrolling through the screen freezes the console output (but not input) during which no further text is printed on the screen, but the program keeps on running as usual. When Scroll Lock is pressed again the screen is unfrozen and all text generated during the freeze is printed at once. This allows the user to pause the display and read long messages that scroll through the screen too quickly to read, for example when the system is booting up.

Comment: OK, so some very niche systems have a use for that key. But - as the question asked - is this *the reason* that key still exists on keyboards?

Comment: What JonW said (and also in the comment to user69530's answer); this sounds like using an existing key because it exists and has no other significant use, as opposed to the reason why that key exists in the first place.